# Python modulo operator giving bad results

Tags: python, modulo

```
>>> m = 3403
>>> 31 % m
31
>>> 031 % m
25
```

I'm using python in terminal testing out RSA. I have no idea why the last line gives the result it does. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a problem with the `%` operator. You accidentally used a Python integer literal feature.

You created an *octal* number by prefixing the number with `0`:

```
>>> 31
31
>>> 031
25
```

That's `3 * 8 + 1`, not `3 * 10 + 1`.

In Python 3 you no longer can create octal numbers this way, you can only use the `0o` prefix.

Comment: PS: In Python 3, `031` raise `SyntaxError: invalid token`.

Comment: Yes, as I said you can no longer use that syntax in Python 3.